# Providing data to Mock for Unit Testing

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, mocking, spring4d

The class I am doing Unit Testing scrolls each record of a DB table and sum the value in a field to the previous value. The following is the class reduced to the bone:

```
procedure TSumList.Sum;
var
  FSum:integer;
begin
  FSum:=0;
  FDB.First;
  while not FDB.EOF do
  begin
    FSum:=FSum+FDB.GetAmount;
    FDB.Next;
  end;
end;
```

FDB refers to the DB mock interface named IIDBTable.

The following is the DB mock for the dependency injection:

```
  IIDBTable = interface
    ['{A299D1D6-93AF-45CC-8DE2-9A4EE188C352}']
    procedure First;
    procedure Next;
    function EOF : boolean;
    function GetAmount:integer;
  end;

  TMockDBTable = class (TInterfacedObject,IDBTable)
    procedure First;
    procedure Next;
    function EOF : boolean;
    function GetAmount:integer;
  end;
```

Problem is I don't know how to provide data to the mock for the test. Of course I can add an extra procedure, say AddValues(aAmount:integer), that does the job but in that case I would end up with this extra procedure in production too and I don't need it.

What is the best practice for this ?

I use Spring for Delphi framework

Comment: Lacks a bit of information:  How to TSumList know about IIDBTable?   Also: The extra method could be on TMockDBTable and not on the interface.   Or you could just pass the data in the constructor of TMockDBTable

Comment: You need to implement the mocking functionality in `TMockDBTable`. Since `TMockDBTable` is providing the implementation of `IDBTable` that is used when testing, you need to make it possible for `TMockDBTable` to receive the mock data. I don't understand why you think you need to add anything to your production code. You didn't put `TMockDBTable` in your production code did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra method to the mock class, `AddValues`. It will exist only in that mock class, not in the real class, so your objection that the extra code would appear in production is unfounded.

I suspect you thought the code would need to be in production because you're dealing with the mock object exclusively through the interface. The extra method would exist in the interface, and would therefore need to be implemented in the production version of the class, even though it doesn't belong there.

Instead, instantiate the `TMockDBTable` and access it through the object reference to set it up however it's needed for the test. Once it's ready, *then* switch to using it via the `IIDBTable` interface.

Another option is to feed the data into the class through a parameter you add to its constructor. Then you don't even need the extra method, and so there's no temptation to define that method on the interface or on the production class. There's no reason your mock class's constructor needs to look like the production class's constructor since the classes aren't related at all. The constructor isn't part of the interface definition.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use DSharp mocks (or Delphi Mocks).

This will be the setup code for DSharp (Delphi Mocks should be similar)

```
var
  mockDBTable: Mock<IIDBTable>;
begin
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillExecute.Once.WhenCalling.First;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(False).Exactly(5).WhenCalling.EOF;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(True).Once.WhenCalling.EOF;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(5).Once.WhenCalling.GetAmount;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(4).Once.WhenCalling.GetAmount;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(3).Once.WhenCalling.GetAmount;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(2).Once.WhenCalling.GetAmount;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillReturn(1).Once.WhenCalling.GetAmount;
  mockDBTable.Setup.WillExecute.Exactly(5).WhenCalling.Next;
```

What you do here is specify what you expect to be called and what to be returned.
This saves you from manually writing a mock class and feed it with data.

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but I find such code to be more of a hindrance than a help. I'm not sure what you've saved yourself from, but I think I'll choose to manually make a mock class every time!

Comment: I agree that in this case the setup code is a bit verbose and doing it like this might not be the best approach because your mock in this case is more data centric. So feeding a "real" IIDBTable instance with test data might be a better approach. But I would not say that writing mock classes every time is the better way. You obviously have not used automatic mocking much. Otherwise you might think different. Also not clear in this example because you are using every method of the interface but you might have cases where you have several methods to implement (even if empty) but only use one.

Comment: Yes, you are right, "every time" is too strong. I'm sure I didn't really mean it to come across like that. I was looking at this one example in isolation. The data centricity makes the automatic mocking approach less attractive here, but I also struggle with the fluent style. Again, maybe through lack of familiarity. I love writing NUnit tests, but when that leads me to fluent style, I find it really hard to read what I am writing. Anyway, +1, this is a good answer.

Comment: The Delphi Mock approach was the first I tried but I didn't know it provides such extended syntax. +1 from me too.

Comment: is my version of Delphi Mock not updated or there is no "Once" available ? I have just downloaded it from https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/Delphi-Mocks by clicking the "Download ZIP" button

Comment: The syntax I showed is the DSharp mocks syntax as I said. But Delphi Mocks also has Once as you can see in Delphi.Mocks.pas

Comment: It seems that in DSharp when I call a method function I need to use Setup.WillReturn(... without calling Setup.WillExecute... before. Is this correct ?

Comment: @piopio Yes, WillReturn when you want to specify the result, WillExecute when you don't or want to provide a delegate that will be executed.